# Problem loading subclasses of hibernate entity

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have an en Entity A which is super class for entities B and C, A is annotated with @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED).

Then another Entity X which has relation to A.

I set x.a with some object of type B, but when I load x, and check type for x.a it is A, and I cannot cast it to B.

I did that a lot of mapping like this before and it was working correctly cannot know what is the problem here.

Also when I do entityManager.find(A.class, id), it also return A although there is an entity B with the same id, it returns B when I run it from Junit test but not when run the application on tomcat server.

Comment: Give us some code to analyze.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you may be getting a proxy instead of the actual instance which is why you can't cast to the subclass. The following may help you unwrap the proxy:

[Converting Hibernate proxy to real object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216547/converting-hibernate-proxy-to-real-object)

Answer (score 0):

You will encounter this problem in connection with the lazy-loading mechanism of Hibernate. Hibernate wraps each object that is lazily loaded into a so-called proxy object. Your object `x.a` will be of type `HibernateProxy`, when you load `x` from database.

I've found this solution useful (similar to @Abdullah's).

[How to unproxy a hibernate object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228838/how-to-unproxy-a-hibernate-object)

You could also eagerly fetch the relation `x.a` to avoid this problem, hence there won't be a proxy-object created.