# How to properly convert List of specific objects to Gson?

Tags: java, json, hibernate, gson

I am working on Spring MVC project. I am using Hibernate. I want to use AJAX with jQuery to get some JSONs from my Spring Controllers. Unfortunately when I was implementing `Gson` methods in my application I have got an error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: 
org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy. Forgot to register a type adapter?
```

Which adapter I have to use and in which way? The error has occurred on the last line of the method:

```
public String messagesToJson(List<Message> messages) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();     
    List<Message> synchronizedMessages = Collections.synchronizedList(messages);
    return gson.toJson(synchronizedMessages, ArrayList.class);
}
```

This is my `Message` class I am using in my Spring MVC project with Hibernate:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MESSAGES", schema = "PUBLIC", catalog = "PUBLIC")
public class Message implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int messageId;
    private User users;
    private String message;
    private Date date;

    //Constructor, getters, setters, toString
}
```

**EDIT**

I am wondering: my `Message` object is proxied or the whole `List<Message>`? I am getting the list of messages in this way:

```
public List<Message> findAllUserMessages(String username) {
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery("from Message where username = :username order by date desc")
            .setParameter("username", username);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Message> messages = query.getResultList();
    return messages;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

No, my `List<Message>` object isn't proxied.

Comment: That's maybe because hibernate creates proxies for your objects. So the parameter `List<Message> messages` cannot handle that proxies. As you see from your stacktrace you are trying to serialize `org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy`. Maybe you can use `cglib` with bytecode manipulations in runtime to avoid creating proxies.

Comment: You should map the Hibernate object to a regular object.

Comment: I have to simply create POJO class similar to Hibernate object but without annotations? @madhead However using `cglib` seems to me a overkill.

Comment: FYI if `List<Message>` was proxified it would not be an instance of `HibernateProxy` but rather of `PersistentCollection`. Beware of what you are testing ;)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I have resolved my problem. The assumption about `HibernateProxy` objects seemed to be very probable. However everything has started to work properly when I have read carefully my error. Finally I have registered type adapter in this way:

```
public String messagesToJson(List<Message> messages) {  
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Message.class, new MessageAdapter()).create();
    return gson.toJson(messages);
}
```

Any my `MessageAdapter` class looks like:

```
public class MessageAdapter implements JsonSerializer<Message> {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Message message, Type type, JsonSerializationContext jsc) {
        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
        jsonObject.addProperty("message_id", message.getMessageId());
        jsonObject.addProperty("message", message.getMessage());
        jsonObject.addProperty("user", message.getUsers().getUsername());
        jsonObject.addProperty("date", message.getDate().toString());
        return jsonObject;      
    }
}
```

And thats all. Now I can get JSONs in jQuery using AJAX properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot woyaru.. I had similar issue but got through it by creating a custom JsonSerializer. :)

Answer (score 2):

As @madhead mentioned in the comments, this happens because, depending on the situation, Hibernate creates proxies around your object, which will call the actual implementation for some methods, and a "instrumented" one for others. Thus, the "actual" type of your objects are HibernateProxy. You can get access to your implementation by using a code similar to the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228838/how-to-unproxy-a-hibernate-object) . In your case, you'd have to call the "unproxy" method for each item in your list, putting them into a new list.

Comment: Unfortunately I have got still the same error. I have implemented in my project `unproxy` method such as you have suggested me.

Comment: I have realized that my objects aren't instances of `HibernateProxy`. So `unproxy` method do nothing in my case. I mean that in this condition `if (entity != null && entity instanceof HibernateProxy)` the result is false.

Answer (score 0):

Though pretty old to answer, I guess by just creating a DTO for Message with String fields would solve the purpose.