# Strange initialization of lazy object in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, jpa

Well, i have class named "Consultation" that have a list of "ItemBudget", and i have a class named "Budget" that have a list of "ItemOrcamento" too. The relation Consultation<-->ItemBudget is ManyToMany, and relation Budget<-->ItemBudget is OneToMany.

In JSF i do the following:

```xml
 <p:dataTable rowKey="#{item.id}" var="item" value="#{consultationMB.consultation.budget.itensAsList}" selection="#{consultationMB.itemBudget}" >
```

I use method "getItensAsList" that return a ArrayList() instead of a HashSet() that primefaces dataTable tag can't read correctly

As you can see, my selection is "itemBudget", so in my ManagedBean called ConsultationMBImpl i try to execute the following:

```java
 if (!itemBudget.getSituation().getCode().equals("WAITING_CONCLUSION")){
    //some code here
 }
```

When i try make the code above all fields that have reference to another class like: Situation, Dentist and others have this: "Dentist_javassist_32", "Situation_javassist_49"...
And all fields are null or zero.

Comment: What about using english names in your code?

Comment: I can translate but this is my original code, because i speak portuguese and my code is all pt-br.

Comment: I already translate my code.

Comment: @bizmark: easier and faster interpretation of the code by ones not familiar with the native language used and therefore generating more chance in getting answers from international community.

Comment: Someone can helpe me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's caused by **Hibernate**, which loads a proxy (suffixed with `_javassist`) instead of the original object. If you debug your code with an IDE and try to call a getter on the fly, you'll get the real value, even it seems to be `null` for the property.

Why is it that done? Because it's much faster to load proxies rather than real objects for the ORM tool. Hibernate [keeps a cache](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/different-between-session-get-and-session-load/) with already loaded objects instead of hitting the DB once and again.

If you want to avoid lazy loading, you could use a [`get`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#get%28java.lang.Class,%20java.io.Serializable%29) instead of a [`load`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#load%28java.lang.Class,%20java.io.Serializable%29) method over Hibernate's Session. Also for its relations, you can mark them as `lazy="false"`, so Hibernate will load them as real objects. If you want to directly unproxy an already loaded instance, there are also [some methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228838/how-to-unproxy-a-hibernate-object) to achieve that.

However, don't do that unless you strictly require it. As I said before, that will make Hibernate load more information from DB and consequently, loose eficiency.

Comment: Very good explanation, reading this and analysing my code i understand my problem. Thanks @XTreme Biker. But i have a doubt: Why use Javassist instead of CGLIB as a Proxy ?

Comment: That's an Hibernate [team's decission](http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/DeprecatedCGLIBSupport).