# How solve JPA lazy load problem with instanceof

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have those jpa Entities

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
class AbstarctAddress {


}

@Entity
public class ConsolidationHub extends AbstarctAddress {

}


@Entity
class Transport {

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "delivery_address_id")
   private AbstarctAddress address;

}
```

when I am doing

```
select t from Transport t left join fetch t.address
```

and then instanceof check like this

t.getAddress() instanceOf ConsolidationHub  it returns `false` . This is because I got hibernate proxy. when I change  to EAGER I don't have that problem. but I don't want to put EAGER since I have performance problems with EAGER.

Do you know how it is possible to solve this issue?

PS. I know that instanceOf check is bad practice, I just need to maintain old code in which there are lots of instanceOf checks and I cannot refactor all of them now.

Comment: I don't know how to make that work in hibernate, sorry. But are you really solving the right issue here. Why not fix the performance issue?

Comment: I have performance problem when I put EAGER,  one way of solving performance problem is to change it to lazy and write JPA query with join fetch(but in that case I got problem with instanceOf). So do youhave some other suggestions ? Thanks.@Jocke

Comment: @user1321466, try t.getAddress().isAssignableFrom(ConsolidationHub.class) with lazy loading.

Comment: "instanceof" is a perfectly valid operation in Java. Other JPA providers dont impose that on you. PS You spelt "Abstract" wrong

Comment: It may not be applicable in your case, and I haven't really tried it, but it may be possible to limit a priori the type of addresses fetched by the query, using the TYPE operator (see section 4.6.17.5 in JPA 2.1 specs). E.g.: `SELECT t FROM Transport t LEFT JOIN FETCH t.address a WHERE TYPE(a)='ConsolidationHub'`. I am not sure if it would actually work with relationships.

Comment: If you want perform instanceOf check, you can use `Hibernate.getClass(proxyObject)`

Comment: In Hibernate 5.2.10 `unproxy` [method](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#unproxy-java.lang.Object-) has been introduced. Maybe you can use it in the getter? It is also doable in older versions with slightly [more code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11228887/1654233).

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid the answer is: start writing OOP code. `instanceof` flies in the face of polymorphism. The clients of a class should *never* care which specific subtype/implementation they are talking to.

If you used entity inheritance, and now need to use `instanceof` in your code, your design is most probably flawed. Hibernate uses proxies on many occasions, and you cannnot rely on `instanceof` or `.getClass()` always returning the exact class of your entity.

If, on the other hand, you've used `instanceof` out of curiosity, and were surprised to find that it actually returns `false`, fear not, all calls you make to this entity proxy are still polymorphic.

The reason why `instanceof` fails here is that Hibernate needs to initialize the lazy property with *something*, and it cannot determine the type of that *something* until the property is loaded. If you insist on using `instanceof`, you may try enabling entity enhancement.