# Problem with proxy when using @IdClass in Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

For legacy reasons I have composite keys in my database, I use @IdClass to map them (before I used @Embeddedid but it had it's own bugs). However I have problem whenever I'm trying to save composite key entity that contains proxy as id field.
I made very simple example to isolate this problem (example uses Spring Data, but I think its irrelevant).
p.s. I know that calling .save is not necessary, but it should not cause exception.

```
@Entity
public class Image {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String fileName;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ProductImage.ProductImageId.class)
public class ProductImage {

    public static class ProductImageId implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 8542391285589067304L;

        private Long product;

        private Long image;

        public ProductImageId() {
        }

        public Long getProduct() {
            return product;
        }

        public void setProduct(Long product) {
            this.product = product;
        }

        public Long getImage() {
            return image;
        }

        public void setImage(Long image) {
            this.image = image;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            ProductImageId that = (ProductImageId) o;
            return Objects.equals(product, that.product) &&
                    Objects.equals(image, that.image);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(product, image);
        }
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Id
    private Product product;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Id
    private Image image;

    private Integer number;

    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public Image getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(Image image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public Integer getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(Integer number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

---

```
    List<ProductImage> productImages = productImageRepository.findAll();
    productImages.get(0).setNumber(456);
    productImageRepository.save(productImages.get(0));
```

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type 'com.example.springbootnewplayground.Product$HibernateProxy$AJ38NiN6' to required type 'java.lang.Long' for property 'product': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor] returned inappropriate value of type 'com.example.springbootnewplayground.Product$HibernateProxy$AJ38NiN6'
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:258) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 69 common frames omitted

Comment: It feels like you are experiencing the issue due too lazy loading . Have you tried to `unproxy` your object first as discussed here ? 
[Converting Hibernate proxy to a real entity object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216547/converting-hibernate-proxy-to-a-real-entity-object) and here
 [how to unproxy a hibernate object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228838/how-to-unproxy-a-hibernate-object)

Comment: probably it will work If I will unproxy whole object structure, but in big project, with big nested structure of classes it will be very ugly. I also think its because of lazy initialization, but it seems like its bug, because at that point proxy still has access to entity manager and it can easily instantiate itself.

Comment: Its not bug, Spring applies transaction management at the repository level, so you will not have acces to your lazy properties outside repository level. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25709976/spring-boot-spring-data-how-are-hibernate-sessions-managed/25710391#25710391

Comment: Its same problem even if I use @Transactional annotation, I know as a fact that on the line where I get error, while debugging if I call methods of proxy entity, I get data and not lazy initialization error.