# JPA/Hibernate instance of not working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Imagine a situation:

```
@javax.persistence.Inheritance(strategy=javax.persistence.InheritanceType.JOINED)
@javax.persistence.DiscriminatorColumn
@javax.persistence.Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name="PARENT")
public abstract class Parent{
...
}

@javax.persistence.Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name="A")
public class A extends Parent{
...
}

@javax.persistence.Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name="B")
public class B extends Parent{
...
}


Parent p = new A();
```

Now we call this:

```
p instance of A
```

always returns **false**!!

works ok on OpenJPA!

Should I file a bug? Hibernate 4.3.10

Comment: If you assign "p" to "new A()" then it is obviously an instanceof A, by basic Java (nothing to do with JPA). If "p" is not an instanceof A then what class is it?

Comment: instanceof returns an instance type, if you created this instance then it should return true, if not you then you should ask who did it.

Comment: Do you really do `Parent p = new A();` or you get `A` from the database by Hibernate?

Comment: Post your real code, the case you described here is obviously impossible.

Comment: True, this is probably a proxy. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32785467/4754790) for more details.

Comment: There are a lot of answers here. But it is unclear what is the question :)

Comment: Actually the problem was a bit deeper and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8770124/hibernate-4-classcastexception-on-lazy-loading-while-eager-works-fine helped me to resolve it. The "Parent" children were used inside of other entity and were set to load in lazy manner.. so it all failed. Thanks for suppoert anyway)

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov that doesn't mean you have to turn off lazy loading. Don't throw the baby out with the bath water! Honestly instanceof is best avoided anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is most likely because hibernate is returning a proxy.

Why does it do this? To implement lazy loading the framework needs to intercept your method calls that return a lazy loaded object or list of objects. It does this so it can first load the object from the DB and then allow your method to run. Hibernate does this by creating a proxy class. If you check the type in debug you should be able to see the actual type is a generated class which does not extend from your base class.

How to get around it? I had this problem once and successfully used the visitor pattern instead of using `instanceof`. It does add extra complication so it's not everyone's favorite pattern but IMHO it is a much cleaner approach than using `instanceof`.

If you use `instanceof` then you typically end up with `if...else` blocks checking for the different types. As you add more types you will have to re-visit each of these blocks. The advantage of the visitor pattern is that the conditional logic is built into your class hierarchy so if you add more types it makes it less likely you need to change everywhere that uses these classes.

I found this [article](https://developer.jboss.org/docs/DOC-13931) useful when implementing the visitor pattern.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure, but I think this will work.

```
public static boolean instanceOf(Object object, Class<?> superclass) {
    return superclass.isAssignableFrom(Hibernate.getClass(object));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to unproxy your object :

```
/**
     * 
     * @param <T>
     * @param entity
     * @return
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> T initializeAndUnproxy(T entity) {
        if (entity == null) {
            // throw new NullPointerException("Entity passed for initialization is null");
            return null;
        }
        Hibernate.initialize(entity);
        if (entity instanceof HibernateProxy) {
            entity = (T) ((HibernateProxy) entity).getHibernateLazyInitializer().getImplementation();
        }
        return entity;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because Hibernate uses run time proxies and OpenJPA, while supporting the proxy approach, prefers either compile time or runtime byte code enhancement.

See:

http://openjpa.apache.org/entity-enhancement.html

```
//Hibernate
Entity e = repository.load(entityId); // may return a proxy 

//OpenJPA
Entity e = repository.load(entityId); //will return an (enhanced) actual instance of E
```

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate returns Proxied Object. Rather than implementing a Visitor pattern (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35065564/5788941)), you can use the `isAssignableFrom()` method on the class you want to test (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom-java.lang.Class-).

Comment: Interesting idea but how is isAssignableFrom going to work if instanceof fails? Surely they both check the class hierarchy?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496928/what-is-the-difference-between-instanceof-and-class-isassignablefrom isAssignableFrom can check class at runtime, wich is good as proxies are generated at runtime

Comment: `instanceof` also checks objects at runtime.

Comment: I think what you mean is that instanceof requires the class name at compile time whereas isAssignableFrom can get the class from an object using getClass. That isn't the problem here though. The instanceof compiled but the runtime object doesn't belong to the type hierarchy due to a proxy.