# JPA @ManyToOne, FetchType.LAZY and FetchMode.SELECT do not load original Parent object

Tags: java, jpa, orm, many-to-one

In my bi-direction JPA association between my Parent-child; I am trying to Lazy load my Parent from my Child Entity through a ManyToOne association.

While I debug, I do get the javaassist Proxy object(something like `Trade_$$_javaassist_41`) which is always a blank object. When I click the Proxy object, JPA does execute the select Query also, but ultimately, no binding happens with the original Parent Object(tradeBean).

Lazy loading the child entity from Parent(OneToMany) doesn't have such issues and child loads without fail.

**Parent Entity(Trade)**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="tradeBean", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL})
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
private Set<Product> products = new LinkedHashSet<Product>();
```

**Child Entity(Product)**

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity=Trade.class)
@JoinColumn(name="Trade", referencedColumnName="TradeID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
private Trade tradeBean;
```

**EntityManager Retrieval**

```
EntityManager manager  = getEntityManager();
productObj = manager.find(Product.class, productPrimarykey);
if (productObj != null){
    productObj.getTradeBean().getTradeID();
}
manager.detach(productObj);         
return productObj;
```

Question [JPA/Hibernate proxy not fetching real object data, sets all properties to null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945365/jpa-hibernate-proxy-not-fetching-real-object-data-sets-all-properties-to-null) has the similar problem statement but there are no final members in my entities.

Comment: targetEntity=Trade.class?????

Comment: With or without `targetEntity=Trade.class`; didn't make any difference.

Comment: Is the problem occurring only in the debugger or in general?

Comment: In General.
In Debug mode i could only see that the Lazy load is indeed happening when i click the entity association. Select query was being executed but still the binding of original object to proxy object is not happening.