# Hibernate session.load() not working with Java reflection getDeclaredFields?

Tags: java, hibernate, reflection

I am running a function that loops through the declared fields, finds the difference between 2 instances of an object and outputs it (for audit trails). However, if I use an object loading from the hibernate session, I.E:

```
HazardSubmission hs = (HazardSubmission)s.load(HazardSubmission.class, id);
```

The declared fields of that object come out at: default_interceptor,handler,_filter,methods where if I load an object of the same type without using session.load it finds the ACTUAL declared fields fine. If I run a getClass().toString() on this hs object, it returns:

```
class nz.co.g.hs.stripes.model.HazardSubmission_$$_javassist_1
```

Where as far as I can tell javaasssist_1 is the problem, for some reason it's not finding the actual class.

Any idea what I can do?

Comment: Solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216547/converting-hibernate-proxy-to-real-object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`session.load(HazardSubmission.class, 1)` will first check if the instance of the type `HazardSubmission.class` with the ID 1 can be found in the current session . If yes , that instance is returned . Otherwise , a proxy will be returned.

Proxies are created dynamically by sub-classing `HazardSubmission.class` .They are not `HazardSubmission.class` and that 's why `getDeclaredFields()` on the returned instance are not the actual `Field` of the `HazardSubmission.class`

To get the actual `Class` from the generated  proxy instance , you can use [Hibernate.getClass()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#getClass%28java.lang.Object%29)

```
HazardSubmission hs = (HazardSubmission)s.load(HazardSubmission.class, id);

System.out.println(Hibernate.getClass(hs).toString());
for (Field field : Hibernate.getClass(hs).getDeclaredFields()) {
    System.out.println(field .toString());
}
```