# Hibernate lazy initilizer issue in glassfish jersy with codehus jackson rest service

Tags: hibernate, glassfish, jersey-2.0

I am working on glashfish jersey rest services with codehus-Jackson for json data.
But i am getting Hibernate lazy initialization exception for that i have added the lazy=false for all child classes. But it was giving infinite recursion error. So i have added JsonIgnore on reverse mapped properties. But it is not detecting. My configuration as follows.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.koderzlab.lawman;org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

My stack trace is as follows

```
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serializeFields(BeanSerializer.java:189)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:142)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serializeFields(BeanSerializer.java:175)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:142)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.ContainerSerializers$CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(ContainerSerializers.java:442)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.ContainerSerializers$CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(ContainerSerializers.java:383)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.ContainerSerializers$AsArraySerializer.serialize(ContainerSerializers.java:142)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serializeFields(BeanSerializer.java:175)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:142)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serializeFields(BeanSerializer.java:175)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:142)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.ContainerSerializers$CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(ContainerSerializers.java:442)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.ContainerSerializers$CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(ContainerSerializers.java:383)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just i have added the codehusjackson 1.9.2 jars now it is recognizing @JsonBack reference. But on each pojo class we need to add
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})

Answer (score 0):

Although your Hibernate problem may not get solved by this, it looks like your are scanning the wrong package name for Jackson classes.

For **Jackson 2.x**, which is normally used with **Jersey 2.x**, you need to scan in the package `com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs` instead of `org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs`.

Change the part in your `web.xml` to the following:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.koderzlab.lawman;com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</param-value>
</init-param>
```

**See also:**

- [Jersey JAX-RS, Hibernate and LazyInitializationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627006/jersey-jax-rs-hibernate-and-lazyinitializationexception)
- [Hibernate org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20162077/hibernate-org-hibernate-lazyinitializationexception-failed-to-lazily-initialize)
- [LazyInitializationException in Hibernate and Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22832346/lazyinitializationexception-in-hibernate-and-jersey)

Comment: Just an FYI, Jersey has a module [jersey-media-json-jackson1](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jackson) which uses the codehaus Jackson. In which case, the OP config would be correct :-)

Comment: Hi @unwichtich thanks for your response. Actually i have tried it but it didn't work and com.koderzlab.lawman is my base package after src folder.

Comment: Then maybe you should update your question with the exception stacktrace.

Comment: Hi @unwichtich please find the stack trace for my issue that i have mentioned . please help me to resolve this issue