# Hibernate 4.3 initialize entities

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, eclipse-kepler

I'm new with Hibernate 4.3 and need initialize the instances of the entities. 
With hibernate 3   I used the Hibernate.initialize() but in the version 4.3 the don't found the command neither the import org.hibernate.Hibernate.

I used the Eclipse Kepler and Wildfly 8.0.

can tell me how to do this?

Thanks

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Issue is with **classpath** only that you are not able to see the imports correctly, also i would recommend to use the below code snippet for intializing proxies.

Create a class **HibernateUtils** and call it's static method.

```
public class HibernateUtils {

    public static <T> T initializeAndUnproxy (T entity) {
        if (entity == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (entity instanceof HibernateProxy) {
            entity = (T) ((HibernateProxy) entity).getHibernateLazyInitializer().getImplementation();
        }

        return entity;
    }


}
```

Comment: what is the difference with the next solution? [hibernate]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216547/converting-hibernate-proxy-to-real-object this use hibernate.intialize

Comment: @Jericob Yeah almost same thing, but the above code snippet is from my project code.

Answer (score 0):

Things to consider :

Have you include hibernate jar files (especially the required jars) in your `lib` folder ?

```
antlr-2.7.7.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
javassist-3.12.1.GA.jar
hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.0.CR2.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
```

this file is from `hibernate` you will download and it will have `required` folder inside `lib`.

`If yes` :

Right click the import which contains error , and click `Fix project` setup and missing `jar files` will be automatically included.