# Play Excel module weird behaviour

Tags: java, excel, hibernate, playframework, jxls

I am using Play with Excel module 1.2.3. In a controller, I get a list of Students by calling a method defined in the model - Student:

```
List<Student> students= Student.findStudents();
```

`findStudents()` is defined as:

```
public static List<Student> findStudents() {
    List<Student> list =  Student.find("colA != colB").fetch();

    return list;
}
```

then I render the excel file by:

```
renderExcel("student_report");
```

Inside the excel template, I have used JXLS. For example:

```
<jx:forEach items="${students}" var="stu">
    ${stu.address.name}                    ${stu.name}
</jx:forEach>
```

Now, the weird thing happens. `stu.name` always get displayed fine. However, `stu.address.name` only get displayed when I have done something like `System.out.println(student.address.name)` in the code. Otherwise, the cell in the Excel report is blank.

Can anyone explain this?

N.B. Student lazily ref to address

Answer (score 0):

Jxls uses Apache Jexl to process property expressions like `stu.address.name`.  Jexl uses reflection to calculate the object property values. 
But reflection and lazy loading do not go along because you work not with a real object but with a proxy object.

When you do `System.out.println(student.address.name)` the real object is instantiated and the reflection works fine.

Possible solution to the issue is described in this answer [Converting Hibernate proxy to real object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216547/converting-hibernate-proxy-to-real-object). Or you just should do eager fetching whenever you need to pass the object to Jxls.