# Prevent Hibernate from returning a proxy in my criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, proxy

Here is my criteria:

```
public Commercial findManager(Entity entity) {
    DetachedCriteria criteria2 = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Role.class);
    criteria2.createAlias("workStation", "workStation");
    criteria2.createAlias("workStation.entity", "entity");
    criteria2.add(Restrictions.eq("entity.id", entity.getId()));
    criteria2.createAlias("commercial", "commercial", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN);
    criteria2.setFetchMode("commercial", FetchMode.JOIN);
    criteria2.createAlias("commercial.function", "function");
    criteria2.add(Restrictions.eq("function.name", "MANAGER"));
    criteria2.setProjection(Projections.property("commercial"));
    Commercial commercial = (Commercial) getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria2).get(0);
    return commercial;
}
```

This criteria works as intended except that it returns a proxy. Since I am going to query a lot of properties on that proxy I want to force hibernate to load that object in the same query, but even with fetchmode in JOIN mode it does not seem to work. What is wrong?

I use hibernate 3.3.2 and spring 2.5

Comment: Are you sure that the returned instance, although a proxy, is not initialized? Take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32785467/4754790).

Comment: You are right, after looking into your suggestion and making further investigation, I figured how that the proxy was actually initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Dragan, I figured out that the proxy was actually initialized. It was actually a bad interpretation of what I was seeing in the JDBC log and in the debugger.

I was seeing this:

[image: Proxy with all fields null]

But when looking deeper into it, I figured out that the data was there, and making logs into the console for the data did not trigger new calls to the database:

[image: Proxy actually Initialized]

After some more investigations I figured out that the `FetchMode.JOIN` and `CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN` in the original request are actually not needed to get this result. But the Adress field, which is a complex object, was not initialized, and querying on its attributes generated new requests to the database. Then I tried to add the following line and now it works like a charm (like in the previous screenshot where we can see that the adress field is a proxy)

```
    criteria2.setFetchMode("commercial.adresse", FetchMode.JOIN);
```