# Hibernate returns proxy for base class

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, spring-data-jpa

I have a hierarchy in my domain model, which is described by classes:

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    // other fields
}

@DiscriminatorValue(value = "Individual")
public class IndividualEntity extends BaseEntity {
    // fields
}

@DiscriminatorValue(value = "Branch")
public class BranchEntity extends BaseEntity {
    // fields
}
```

I'm fetching objects like this:

```
Specification<BaseEntity> specification = createSpecification();
BaseEntity entity = baseRepository.findOne(specification);
```

(I'm using spring-data)

The problem is that Hibernate returns proxy object (what I understand), but the proxy is of `BaseEntity`, not the proper subclass (its' class is `BaseEntity_$$_jvsted9_26`, therefore `entity instanceof IndividualEntity` is false).

What is interesting, not all objects are returned as proxy.
I'm fetching entities in loop (common transaction), some of them are returned in normal form (i.e. `IndividualEntity`/`BranchEntity`), some as proxies.
If I change mechanism, so that every fetch is done in separate transaction - no proxy objects are returned at all.

I know that I can unwrap that proxy (e.g. like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216547/converting-hibernate-proxy-to-real-object)), but what is the reason for such behaviour (kinda strange for me) and can I avoid it?

Comment: I'm having the same problem using directly spring-data Repository class.

Comment: Why do you care?

Comment: Might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32785467/4754790.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't be certain without seeing more of the object model, but one reason Hibernate would do this is if the BaseEntity had already had to be resolved as a proxy for the same `BaseEntity.id` earlier in the session.

For example, if there is another class that has a ToOne relation to a `BaseEntity`, it will just have a foreign key to the `id`, so will use a `BaseEntity_$$...` proxy to delay resolving the correct subclass for the other end.  This then becomes the instance for that `id` that is managed in the Hibernate `PersistenceContext`.

Clearly a `Hibernate.unwrap()`, or one of the other options in the link above will reveal the 'true' instance.  One other option is to use abstract methods on `BaseEntity` (e.g. `isIndividual()`).  This can look a bit tidier, but ultimately Hibernate will still need to resolve the proxy when the method is called.

Comment: Yes, that sounds reasonable! I've dealt with that using Visitor pattern, btw. Thanks for this info!