# Orika class is not accessible

Tags: spring, hibernate, orika

When mapping from a DTO to a hibernate entity I get following exception:

> ma.glasnost.orika.MappingException: ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.CompilerStrategy$SourceCodeGenerationException: class com.exmaple.MyEntity_$$_jvst402_4 is not accessible

The entity is public.

Versions:

- spring-boot-starter-data-jpa: 1.4.0.RELEASE
- orika: 1.4.6
- hibernate: 5.0.9.Final.

Comment: Any private fields within Entity? If yes, have you added getters and setters for them?

Comment: No private fields.  It is failing at classPool.get(className).  It is as if javassist does not know about the class.  I have seen this work before with hibernate + spring + orika without effort.

Comment: Ok, any inner classes then? The dollar sign in your entity suggests there is an inner class that couldn't be accessed.

Comment: I thought it indicated the proxy object that hibernate created ?

Comment: Is your entity class auto generated using Javaassist? May be it generates the entity with an inner class?

Comment: My class is 'hand written'.  When I call mySpringDataJpaRepository.findOne(id) it returns the MyEntity _$$_jvst class.

Comment: Please see if this post helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216547/converting-hibernate-proxy-to-real-object May be you should extract the real Entity object from Hibernate Proxy before transformation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123820/discussion-between-ben-george-and-programmer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error can occur when the mapping is not configured correctly.  The error can be very very misleading.

Configuration that caused the error:

```
factory.classMap(MyEntity.class, MyEntity.class).byDefault().register();
```

The fix

```
factory.classMap(MyEntity.class, MyEntityDTO.class).byDefault().register();
```

---

I considered deleting this question as it is not an issue with any of the libraries but essentially a typo/copypasto in my mapping configuration. However for reasons best described by [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/979) I shall let it remain.