# Hibernate envers "cannot evaluate $HibernateProxy$.toString()"

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I am using envers to audit my entities. My code looks somewhat like this

```java
@Audited( targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED )
@AuditOverride( forClass = Task.class, isAudited = true )
public class Job extends Task
{...}

@Inheritance( strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED )
@Audited( targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED )
public class Task
{ 
    ...
    @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    @LazyToOne( value = LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY )
    @Fetch( value = FetchMode.SELECT )
    @JoinColumn( nam = "id_util" )
    @Audited( targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.AUDITED )
    private Utility utility;
}

@Entity
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@Audited( targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED )
public class Utility
{
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append( this.getClass().getName() ).append( "@" ).append( getId() );
        builder.append( "[" );
        appendAttributeValues( builder );
        builder.append( "]" );
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public Long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
}
```

When I try to fetch the revisions of a certain `job` entity, the field `utility` is not loaded correctly. Instead, hibernate gives a

```
Method threw 'org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException' exception. Cannot evaluate Utility$HibernateProxy$9GVDBIUC.toString()
```

The rest of the entity revisions which consists of strings and numbers is loaded just fine. I also don't get this error when auditing and querying other entities which do not have an inheritance structure.

The `_aud` tables for the entities `Job`, `Task` and `Utility` are all filled correctly. What might be causing this error?

Comment: Can you include the code of the ```Utility``` entity also? Thanks

Comment: The utility contains simple types and references to other entitites different from the ones regarding this problem. I added the annotations I am using.

Comment: Please, can you at least include the ```toString``` method definition of the entity, if any?

Comment: toString() included

Comment: Thank you. And what is the definition of the method ```appendAttributeValues```? I am sorry to ask, the problem could be related with some code in the implementation of the method ```toString``. Say, for instance, that you reference a relation that does not exists or something like that. If it is not the case, we can think in others reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR** The reason is inconsistent audit data. It happens when you you start auditing already existing entities and their relations.

**Solution** Copy all entity data in the corresonding `aud` table with `rev = 1`,`revtype = 0`. Insert `rev=1`, `revtstmp=0` into `revinfo` table.

See also [Safe Envers queries when the audit history is incomplete](https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/safe-envers-queries-when-the-audit-history-is-incomplete/771)

**Explanation** Because the entity data existed before envers is integrated, the audit tables are initially empty. When you update an entity **A** whichs owns a reference to entity **B**, an audit records is created in `A_aud` but not in `B_aud`. When **A** is queried for revisions it tries to look up the referred entity **B** in the emtpy `B_aud` and yields an `EntityNotFoundException`, which got wrapped up in the given `GenericJDBCException`.

Comment: can you describe how to fix this problem?

Comment: Quick solution added. Its is described further in the linked hibernate forum post.

Answer (score 1):

Before using linked object you should "materialize" proxy-object created by hibernate, like sayed in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2216603/3744622

```java
Hibernate.initialize(entity);
if (entity instanceof HibernateProxy) {
    entity = (T) ((HibernateProxy) entity).getHibernateLazyInitializer()
        .getImplementation();
}
return entity;
```

or, for instance, using special method `unproxy`:

```java
Object unproxiedObject = Hibernate.unproxy(proxiedObject);
```